# Confirmation message on comment submission

Tags: forms, comments, 9

When a comment is submitted, no confirmation message is shown and I would like to achieve this. I want to show the following message.

> Your comment has been added for review and approval.

I tried this code.

```php
function mymod_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  else if ($form_id == 'comment_comment_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = "your comment has been added for review and approval"
  }
}
```

This only edits the submission button text. Is there a way to add a submission confirmation message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal already shows a similar message, to the users who has the *post comments* permission but not the *skip comment approval* permission.
There is no need to use custom code for that: Don't give the *skip comment approval* permission to the users whose comments must be approved.

If the purpose is changing the message shown by Drupal in that case (*Your comment has been queued for review by site administrators and will be published after approval.*), it's enough to change the message Drupal uses, for example adding the following line to the settings.php file.

```php
$settings['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = [
  'Your comment has been queued for review by site administrators and will be published after approval.' => 'Your comment has been added for review and approval',
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The above snippet doesn't overwrite the language I still see "Your comment has been added for review and approval". the updated message is not showing.

Comment: btw, I copy pasted the above lines to settings.php and cleared cache. still I cannot see the language changed

Comment: @chaydru – I think you need to translate the message now on the interface translation page.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: @chaydru This method is still documented in the [default.settings.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21default%21default.settings.php/9.3.x) file for Drupal 9.3.x, so it's the method to change strings used by a Drupal core module.

Comment: The comment in the *default.settings.php* file says: _To override specific strings on your site with or without enabling the Locale module, add an entry to this list. This functionality allows you to change a small number of your site's default English language interface strings._

Comment: Agree. Let me check my settings just once again. First time when I made this change, it didn't reflect

Comment: Thanks @apaderno this solution worked

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a custom submit handler, and set your message there.

```
function ahrq_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    else if($form_id == 'comment_comment_form') {
       $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'ahrq_comment_form_submit';
    }
}

function ahrq_comment_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus->($this->t('Your comment has been added for review and approval'));
}
```